# Nori fundamental group and etale fundamental group in positive characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, characteristic-p, fundamental-group

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface over an algebraically closed field of char $p > 0$. Suppose that $\pi_{1}^{et}(X) = \{1\}$. Can Nori fundamental group scheme of $X$ be non-trivial?

Comment: A non-classical Enriques surface in characteristic 2?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, but unfortunately, I don't understand why it should be the case.

Comment: Because it admits a non-trivial $\alpha_2$ or $\mu_2$-torsor, hence the fundamental group scheme should be either $\alpha_2$ or $\mu_2$.